# Attribute error in tkinter: move is not defined

Tags: python

Attempting to create a program that will simple move a rectangle from one position to another in the tkinter canvas. I have seen examples using the move(item,x,y) command. I am unsure why it still presents the error  AttributeError: 'tkapp' object has no attribute 'move'.
I have tried shuffling around the code and rewriting it to no avail.

Any tips as to where I went wrong would be great thanks.

Code:

```
from tkinter import *
import time 
root = Tk()
root.geometry("750x500")  
canvas = Canvas(root,width=750, heigh = 500)
canvas.pack()
a = canvas.create_rectangle(0,100,25,0, fill = 'red')
b = canvas.create_rectangle(50,90,25,0, fill = 'blue')
c = canvas.create_rectangle(75,80,50,0, fill = 'yellow')
time.sleep(5)
root.move(c,150,50)
root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're using `move` on the wrong object. `root` is your main app of the `tkapp` class, whereas you want to move the rectangle on the canvas. So, in order to make this work, use

```
canvas.move(c, 150, 50)
```

instead.

**Edit:**
By the way, the rectangle is moved before the window is showing. Try putting `time.sleep` and `canvas.move` into a seperate function and call it seperately, e.g. through a button, to watch the rectangle move.

Comment: Thank you, works as intended now. Your edit is a pretty good suggestion, I'll impliment when I've learnt the use of buttons in the next iteration of the program.

Comment: Glad i could help! and Happy Holidays ;-)